# Measure website loading time with screenshots each second

Tags: pagespeed

Is there a software, online tool or script to meaure how fast a website loads and also includes screenshots of the website second by second during the time the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) out for the load speed test.

If you want screenshots, you can try developing a program that does so, but that would require quite a bit of time and effort. Sadly, I am not aware of any such software suites.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I came across http://gtmetrix.com for analyze the performance of your site.This will give automatic report of famous pagespeed and Yslow at a time.We can also compare two sites with this and also have an option to download pdf of the report .Check with the URL May be help full to you.